# How Browsers Work of modern web browsers

Tags: cookies, webbrowser-control

What are the components of a browser,Which are the settings that control a browser, how cookies works ,how browser sessions work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge topic here. Rather than break this down and write forever, I will go through a web scenario: User types in address (or clicks a link?) - NOTE: a bit oversimplified

1. Browser breaks down URI
2. Browser checks cache to see if site IP address is in cache
3. If no, browser contacts DNS server to get IP address
4. Browser creates request for resource at URI, which is a package that has both a header (for routing) and a body (the request). For a page address typed in or click, it will be a GET request. The browser also sends a collection of "capabilities" like I accept cookies, etc.
5. Server contacted and returns a response.
6. Browser breaks down the response. It may be a success or failure and there will be a return code either way.
7. Assuming success, the browser then parses the message and breaks it into the HTML for the page and any collections sent (for example cookies)
8. For cookies, the browser checks user preferences before storing. It should be noted there is more than one type of cookie today. There are user cookies, which contain user information and can be easily blocked by the user and server cookies, which contain information needed by the application server. The later can also be blocked, if desired, but it is generally not advised as you lose functionality.
9. The HTML is parsed so the page can be displayed (rendering engine) and all resources required to see the page (like pictures) are requested through a new web request and rendered on the page.

Components? You can derive some here. Request creator, response parser, page renderer, configuration (both standard and user), etc.

Settings? Too numerous to cover. Open a browser and look at settings to see quite a few.

Cookies? Covered the basics already.

Sessions? Handled by server cookies. If you restrict them you can only get one page at a time, unless some information is passed in the URI on each request.